# Cannot convert expression type 'lambda expression' to return type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<IProduct,string,bool>>'

Tags: c#, lambda

Ok, I'm lost.  Why is the 1st function WRONG (squiglies in the lambda expression), but the 2nd one is RIGHT (meaning it compiles)?

```
    public static Expression<Func<IProduct, string, bool>> IsValidExpression(string val)
    {
        return (h => h.product_name == val);

    }

    public static Expression<Func<IProduct, bool>> IsValidExpression2()
    {
        return (m => m.product_name == "ACE");

    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first function is going to need two arguments.  [**`Func<x,y,z>`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) defines two parameters and the return value.  Since you have both an `IProduct` and a `string` as parameters, you'll need two arguments in your lambda.

```
  public static Expression<Func<IProduct, string, bool>> IsValidExpression(string val)
  {
        return ((h, i) => h.product_name == val);
  }
```

Your second function is only `Func<x,y>`, so that means that the function signature has but one parameter, and thus your lambda statement compiles.

Answer (score 3):

What is the middle `string` intended to do? You can make it compile by:

```
public static Expression<Func<IProduct, string, bool>> IsValidExpression(string val)
{
    return (h,something) => h.product_name == val;
}
```

Or maybe you mean:

```
public static Expression<Func<IProduct, string, bool>> IsValidExpression()
{
    return (h,val) => h.product_name == val;
}
```

?

Comment: My guess is that OP is unaware that val is hoisted and hence not part of the signature for the resulting method of the lambda expression

Answer (score 0):

`Func<IProduct, string, bool>` is a delegate to a method with the following signature:

```
bool methodName(IProduct product, string arg2)
{
  //method body
  return true || false;
}
```

so

```
public static Expression<Func<IProduct, string, bool>> IsValidExpression(string val)
{
    return (h => h.product_name == val);
}
```

has a differance between the return type and the returned value. you are trying to return an object of the type `Expression<Func<IProduct, bool>>`.

the val argument is not an argument to the method you're delegating to but will be hoisted (made part of a class implementing the resulting function) and since it's not an argument to the resulting method it should not be part of the `Func` type delclaration

Comment: Since this is an `Expression` (not a delegate) it isn't quite as you describe - there **is** no "resulting function"; it is an expression tree...

Comment: @marc You're right on the Expression<> being an Expression tree and not a method I strungled for a term for "The method that the Expression tree can be compiled into" which I tryed to formulate as "resulting function" however the statment that well Func<> is a delegate type is correct :)

Answer (score -1):

> Before trying to fix the lambda expression be sure that the following references were added to the related cs file:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
```

The lack of these references may cause the same error as well (*"Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Lambda Expression' because it is not a delegate type"*).